# Icons8 Lunacy says: "Missing Fonts" even though they are installed on my PC?

Tags: fonts, mockups, sketchapp

I was given a sketch file, and since I have Windows, I installed Icons8 Lunacy to read that file, but when I try to open the file, I get a message saying that a font called (Avenir-Heavy) is missing even though I installed it on my PC for the third time and I can see on my Fonts settings that it's there, some fonts were missing also in the start but managed to install them and they were removed from the "missing fonts" error message, yet (Avenir-Heavy) is stuck there, I don't know why ?!

Can somebody help me fix this please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

There will be huge update soon with the improved font searching and other fixes and features. For now you can write us to lunacy@icons8.com
Send us sketch file so we can check out how to fix the problem, or request latest dev build.

Also you can install Lunacy from windows store. We publish there updates more often.

Igor
Lunacy Developer

Comment: I don't find sending the design a solution, there should be a general fix or tip to solve that.

Comment: I'm using the version from Windows Store and is better than from the internet version. Thanks